# Create users with AWS .net SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create users with AWS .net SDK to apply permissions (limited access to folders). There will a folder for each user in a bucket, user will be able to access only allotted folder.

So in short my script will be doing this:

- Create AWS user
- Create folder in a bucket for the user created in step#1
- Grant access to folder create in step#2 to user created in step#1

Comment: I would recommend that you only create the user and use a single policy on the user group which [uses the `aws:username` variable](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke) to grant them access to their own folder. Then you only have one policy to maintain when something needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create AWS User**

To create your user in AWS Identity & Access Management (IAM), use the [`CreateUser()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/IAM/MIAM_IAMServiceCreateUser_CreateUserRequest.html) request.

**2. Create Folder**

**There is no need to create a folder.** Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. Rather, the key name (filename) includes the path of the object. So, `bar.jpg` stored in folder `foo` would have a Key of `foo/bar.jpg`. The pretend folder will automatically appear (sort of) when you create an object in that location.

**3. Grant Access to Folder**

A single IAM policy using a variable can be used to grant *all users* access to their own sub-path (effectively a folder) within a bucket.

From [IAM Policy Variables Overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```